# How can I delete a line from a file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, replace

I looked online and found a command similar to this

```
Get-Content .\aws_hosts | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch '([^\.0-9])'} | Set-Content out.txt
```

All that did was copy the line to an out.txt file. I'm trying to figure out how to delete a line from the .\aws_hosts file.

In my aws_hosts file, I want to specifically delete the IP address on line 2 and not the [servers] line

```
[servers]
35.35.35.25
```

Here's the linux version of what I'm trying to do (It's from a Terraform tutorial and they're using Linux, I just can't figure out how to do it using Powershell)

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]/d' aws_hosts
```

Comment: Are you looking to ignore specifically IP addresses or numeric digits and literal dots?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I got a command to write an IP address to a file so I can use it for a service like Ansible. This happens when I create my virtual machine, but when I delete this virtual machine I need it to delete the ip address from the file and I just need to provide a powershell command to remove that IP address from the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the same [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) as you would with `sed`:

```sh
Get-Content .\aws_hosts |
  Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^[0-9]' } | 
    Set-Content out.txt
```

For smallish files (which most text files are), you can simplify to:

```sh
@(Get-Content .\aws_hosts) -notmatch '^[0-9]' | Set-Content out.txt
```

This simplified approach - due to reading the entire input file *in full* up front - also allows you to write the results back to the same file, as `sed -i` would.